# Laravel Authentication Custom Rule

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm working with laravel Auth. Trying to add new rule with email and password, if status(field in user model) is =  1 then he cannot login. I cannot find where should i add this. I was looking at middleware, guard.php AuthenticateUsers.php but did not found it..

---

Edit:

I've solved this by creating new middleware that checks for this field. Also it can be done with Auth::attempt

Comment: what is status here?

Comment: @MohamedAthif Status is field in User model (edited first post)

Comment: you could make a middleware and restrict routes like admin from him if he has a status of 1

Comment: @MohamedAthif If he has status of 1 i don't want him to be able to log in at first place. I'm thinking there must be function that check if email/pw combo is right, so i can just add one more line there but i cannot find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users)

> If you wish, you also may add extra conditions to the authentication query in addition to the user's e-mail and password.

Comment: Referring to documentation this is supposed to be in LoginController.php but it is not.. Where should i add this code ?

Comment: In `LoginController.php` there is a trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` which contains `login()` function. You can override that function in your `LoginController` class as you required.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your LoginController:

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user with custom credentials into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

    $credentials['status'] = 1; // Additional field you want to check

    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $credentials, $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

Here we add the `status` field as a part of checked credentials. If user has `status` not equal to `1`, authentication will fail.

Works with Laravel5.6